# Error in exporting raphaeljs to jpg with path background as image

Tags: php, javascript, svg, raphael

I have a problem with raphaeljs export plugin ( https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.Export ). 
in a path element I use attribute `fill` and as a source I give a image url to fullfill. But when I export this to SVG I see a path element definition, but when I export it to PNG, I do not see again.

So in my app I add an `attr` to `path` element like this:

```
paper.path("M 195 10 L 300  L 195 z").attr({'stroke-width': 0,'fill': 'url(images/alfen/02/murek.png)'});
```

and I export this with `paper.toSVG()`

and in my SVG I find a path:

```
<path transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" fill="url(images/alfen/02/murek.png)" stroke="#000" d="M203,183.94389438943895L948,183.94389438943895L948,195L203,195Z" stroke-width="0"></path>
```

But when I transform this to PNG with:

```
<?php 
    $json        = $_POST['json'];
    $output      = str_replace('\"','"',$json);
    $filenameSVG = 'test';

    file_put_contents("$filenameSVG.svg", $output);

    $konwert = "convert $filenameSVG.svg $filenameSVG.jpg";

    system($konwert);
```

I cannot find this path fulfilled with my background. Can anybody help?

Comment: A quick guess: either provide the full url (with domain name), or if that fails, a local path to the image (in the `fill` attribute)? `convert` doesn't know your website, domain, or anything about it.

Comment: in my svg i also have `<image transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" width="108" height="48" xlink:href="images/alfen/alfenlogo.png"></image>` and this is converted properly

Comment: Yes, and it does not start with `url(` there, and it can be interpreted as a local path. But why argue? Test I tell ya! :)

Comment: you are right that i just should simpy try.. however i have checked and still nothing. on my webpage everything is ok. on my svg i have full url (http://....) i dont know if it is important but on my code inspector this path i have as `<path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " fill="url(#1AA92631-6253-4B49-91D8-698D42237F32)" stroke="#000000" d="M259,175.65181518151815L948,175.65181518151815L948,195L259,195Z" stroke-width="0"></path>` any idea?

Comment: You might try it with a local file path, but if that doesn't work and nobody else answers: I'm gone for now, but if you pastebin your the complete svg xml somewhere I'll see if I can take a crack at it tomorrow.

Comment: i have also tried to put manually in svg `<defs><pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100"><image xlink:href="images/alfen/02/murek.png" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" /></pattern></defs>` and i have converted it via php's `'convert test.svg test.jpg';` but still nothing

Comment: @gerpaick confused with PNG ,JPG SVG  ?? Well if you want to convert SVG to JPG or PNG then u can use canvg http://code.google.com/p/canvg/ and then you can convert canvas into image easily.Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to get correct output to svg but it fails going to png in php there are several things you'll need to check.

- As a sanity check make sure your $_POST['json'] is not returning malformed json
- The next line in your php confuses me: `$output = str_replace('\"','"',$json);`
- It could be that the json you're returning is a single object, but I'm still not sure why you are searching the entire file and not looking for a specific nested object like `$output = str_replace('\"','"',$json['filename_and_path']);` and if the json you return IS a single line, there may be better ways to handle it -- i.e. post it as a string or even return each one with an array and index.

And for this stuff:

```
$konwert = "convert $filenameSVG.svg $filenameSVG.jpg";
system($konwert);
```

You may not be feeding `system()` with valid variables in your string. To be sure I recommend properly concatenating the string like:

```
$konwert = "convert".$filenameSVG.".svg ".$filenameSVG.".jpg";
```

You're also going to need the absolute filepath to the file on your server to execute the command on or else it won't find the file. The code `$konwert = "convert".$filenameSVG.".svg ".$filenameSVG.".jpg";` is obviously only going to work for you if those two files are located in the root directory of your project.

I also don't think you should be using `system()` in this instance. My understanding is you should be using `passthru()` for dealing with image binaries. There's also `exec()` but really, I think what you need here is `passthru()`. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your path is just setting up a container for the image.  Couldn't you use:

```
paper.image('images/alfen/02/murek.png', 50, 50, 300, 195);
```

It seems like it may be more reliable.  You could use that as your starter and add whetever paths you like to it.  I've had problems using an image as a fill because they never seem to render where I expect them to.

And you can still use: `paper.toSVG()`

I was able to get that version to convert without any trouble.